# How to ask design question in stackexchange

Tags: discussion

I keep getting into trouble with the moderators. Often, I need high level advice how to tackle a problem and then I can go about implementing it. I keep getting my questions on hold because they are too generic.

Is there an acceptable way to ask concepts where one is trying to gett a solution? Often my question is put on hold and one kind soul will actually answer the question which is often what I was looking for. But I'd prefer not to be delinquent on the list. I am just trying to pick the experts brains.

What to do?

Comment: Take the time to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Be very clear and specific about what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck. Try to apply the tags relevant to features you will use and no others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main thing to do is read help pages on asking questions: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help.

If you ask about broad design issues, the answer is likely to be opinion-based. If you do not include your own thoughts/attempts, it's likely to be viewed as a poor question.

Design questions can be valid questions, but you have to bring a bit of information into your question to make it more specific e.g.

Don't ask something like "I need to update an Account from a Contact, what's the best solution?".

Instead, ask "I need to do update an Account from Contact... I've considered Process Builder and Apex. I heard that Process Builder can be less efficient, but I prefer to use declarative solutions. What are the trade-offs?"

The second question is still pretty opinion-based, but at least you've done some homework. And, asking for more details (e.g. how many records in the system? Is performance a real worry?) can lead to there being an actual best answer.